# Proof that if the sum of the differences of consecutive terms of a sequence between any two terms is bounded above by one, then the sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Someone asked me to help them with the following real analysis problem and it's been bugging me that I haven't been able to figure it out or think of something new to try for about a day now:

Suppose it holds for a sequence $\{a_j\}$ of complex numbers that for every pair of integers $N>M>0$, $$\lvert a_M-a_{M+1}\rvert+\lvert a_{M+1}-a_{M+2}\rvert+\ldots+\lvert a_{N-1}-a_{N}\rvert\le1.$$ Prove that $\{a_j\}$ converges.

It was clear to both of us that we have to show that the sequence is Cauchy. I tried contradiction a few times, though I (apart from negating the definition incorrectly a few times) couldn't begin to place where the contradiction would arise. I get that we must have $\lvert a_M-a_N\rvert\le1$, but can't see how that would imply that it's arbitrarily small. After thinking about it on my own, I realised that the smallest difference between consecutive terms must be no greater than $\frac{1}{N-M}$, but the largest one could theoretically be arbitrarily close to $1$, so I don't really see how that's helpful.

And that's about where I've been stuck for about a day. If anyone can give me hints about where to go, I'd appreciate it.

Also, yes, despite the exercise concerning a complex sequence, it *is* for a real analysis course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded since
\begin{align*}
|a_n -a_1| 
&= |(a_n - a_{n-1}) + (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) + \cdots + (a_2 - a_1)|\\[4pt]
&\le |a_n - a_{n-1}| + |a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}|+ \cdots + |a_2 - a_1|\\[4pt]
&\le 1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It follows that the sequence $(a_n)$ has at least one limit point.

Suppose the sequence $(a_n)$ has two distinct limit points $u,v$, say. Let $\theta = |u-v|$.

Construct a subsequence $b_1,b_2,b_3,...$ of the sequence $(a_n)$ such that

- $|b_n - u| < {\large{\frac{\theta}{3}}}$ for all odd $n$.$\\[12pt]$

  $|b_n - v| < {\large{\frac{\theta}{3}}}$ for all even $n$.

It follows that $|b_{n+1}-b_n| >  {\large{\frac{\theta}{3}}}$, for all n.

For each $n$, there are positive integers $j,k$, with $j < k$ such that $b_n = a_j$ and $b_{n+1} = a_k$. Then
$$\frac{\theta}{3} < |b_{n+1}-b_n| 
= |(a_k-a_{k-1}) + \cdots + (a_{j+1}-a_j)| 
\le |a_k-a_{k-1}| + \cdots + |a_{j+1}-a_j| 
$$
But then, summing the LHS for all $n$ yields $\infty$, whereas summing the RHS for all $n$ yields at most $1$, contradiction.

It follows that the sequence $(a_n)$ can't have two distinct limit points, hence, since the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded, it must converge.

Comment: If their book is similar to mine in that it introduces subsequences and subsequential limits before Cauchy sequences, then this should work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your $$\lvert a_M-a_{M+1}\rvert+\lvert a_{M+1}-a_{M+2}\rvert+\ldots+\lvert a_{N-1}-a_{N}\rvert\le1$$
means that the partial sums of the positive series $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}|a_n-a_{n+1}|$$ are bounded, i.e. the series converges. But that means that $$\sum^\infty_{n=M}|a_n-a_{n+1}|\to0$$ as $M\to\infty,$ and $$|a_N-a_M|\le\sum^N_{n=M}|a_n-a_{n+1}|\le\sum^\infty_{n=M}|a_n-a_{n+1}|$$ for $N>M,$ so it is a Cauchy sequence.
Alternatively, you could say that $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}(a_n-a_{n+1})$$ is convergent, because it converges absolutely, and its sum is $$a_1-\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n.$$

Comment: I don't know that the book they were using (it's different than the one I am) has introduced any theorems relating convergence of sequences to convergence of series at this point, and mine hasn't done too many either, so this is a little hard to follow. Is there an alternate method?

Answer (score 0):

Write $A_N$ for $\sum_{n=1}^N|a_{n}-a_{n+1}|$. Can you show that $A_N$ converges, and hence is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: As I commented on Professor Vector's post, I haven't really been introduced to too many theorems relating convergence of sequences to convergence of series. That said, I'm curious about how {A_n} being Cauchy implies {a_j} is Cauchy

Comment: That's because $A_{N-1}-A_{M-1}=|a_M-a_{M+1}|+...+|a_{N-1}-a_N|\geq|a_M-a_N|$. (I should have defined $A_N$ as the sum up to $N-1$ so that this worked out neater, sorry.)

Comment: Oh, that's actually perfectly understandable. Thank you.